# Removing the displayModeButton in UISplitViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to remove the displayModeButton from the detailViewController's Navigation Bar in splitveiwconroller. I tried setting leftBarButtionItem.isEnable = false in AppDelegate.swift file(as below)

```
if let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController {
            let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
            navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
            }
```

it hides the displaymodebutton intially when the application start. But when i swipt right to open the master view and then swipe left to dismiss the masterview controller the dispaly mode buttom reappars again. Please help me to hide the displayModeButton from detail view conroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same in master viewController `viewWillAppear`:

```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = controller 
if let splitViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController {

let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?. isEnabled = false
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?. tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
     }
```

OR if above does not work, use below code in AppDelegate

```
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)
```

Comment: still after dismissing the master view Controller the displaymodeButton is reappearing .

Comment: getting this error : Value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'isHidden' .

Comment: Getting the same issue after resolving this error: 'enabled' has been renamed to 'isEnabled'

Comment: Did you try this: navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)

Comment: I just tried the same. Still, it reappears after dismissing master view.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing this in viewWillAppear

Comment: Put breakpoint in viewWillAppear if it does not call then use NSNotification on dismiss and perform the same code.

Comment: yes, I am doing this in viewWillAppear of masterviewcontroller.

Comment: Ok please put breakpoint in viewWillAppear and check you get it or not.

Comment: Hi @Daljeet, I tried navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true) in Appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it is now working . No need to add in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Hi Daljeet, this code is working fine on the iPad but not working on the iPhones. I found one more way navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true) which hide the button on both iPad's and iPhone's but when I'm using this I am not able to open master view in iPhones, for iPads its working fine. Do you know any way to make it work for iPhones.

Comment: This should work on both, not working because of some other issue you can create a new ticket. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help @Daljeet, I will create a new ticket for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to Daljeet's answer we can also use navigationItem.setHidesBackButton  on the detailview controller or use this in the AppDelegate.swift's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
if let splitViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController {

let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Alternate to setHidesBackButton method, we can also use detailViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true